# How to find a point value on a 2D surface?

Tags: graphing-functions, surfaces

[image: Point on surface]

I was struggling for a while... Can anyone help me find a formula to solve this problem for any point?
Thanks!

UPDATE: I was trying to simplify, but in our case, each number in the corner represents driving time minutes. And each side of this square is 5 mile straight line on a map. What we are trying to achieve, is to approximate driving time to any point on this square (part of the map)

For example, if chosen point is close to 40, then 40 will have most influence on the point's value, but still all 4 numbers should be taken into account.

I'm thinking that this can be represented as a 3D contour graph, where those values are Z dimension.

Comment: What do $20,40,45,90$ represent?  For example $45-20 \not = 90-40$

Comment: Can you give a verbal explanation of what the numbers on the diagram represent and what exactly you want to find.

Comment: I'm going to take a shot in the dark and guess that you have a quadrilateral in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the numbers at the four corners are the values of a $z$-coordinate of the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of the corners. Is this close?

Comment: @Henry I've updated the description.

Comment: @john-wayland-bales I've updated the description.

Comment: So I see.  Try my answer with percentages close to $0\%$ and/or $100\%$ by changing the exponents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have interpreted your problem correctly, then I believe it will be

in general

$$ Z=(1-p_2)[20(1-p_1)+40p_1] +p_2[45(1-p_1)+90p_1]$$

but I must caution that your problem is vaguely stated so I cannot be sure if this is what you are looking for.

If $C_1=20,C_2=40,C_3=45,C_3=90 $ this formula can be re-written

$$ (1-p_1)(1-p_2)C_1+p_1(1-p_2)C_2+p_2(1-p_1)C_3+p_1p_2C_4  $$

and represents a double direct proportion on a flat surface.

[image: 3D diagram of problem]

Comment: When I increase percentages to 99% each:
[20+0.99(40-20)]+0.99[45+0.99(90-45)]
This gives 128.4545 in result, which is not possible...

Comment: I will double-check my logic.

Comment: I found and corrected the error in my formula.

Comment: Note that if $p_1=p_2=0$ then $Z=C_1=20$. If $p_1=0,p_2=1$ then $Z+C_2=40$. If $p_1=1,p_2=0$ then $Z=C_3=45$ and if $p_1=1,p_2=1$ then $Z=C_4=90$. If both $p_1$ and $p_2$ equal $\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $Z=48.75$ which is the average of the four numbers and is in the geometrical center.

Comment: Your answer is good enough for our case! Thank you John!

Answer (score 0):

Moving horizontally across a full edge seems to multiply by $2.25$ while moving vertically across a full edge seems to multiply by $2$, so perhaps the answer is $$20 \times \left(\dfrac{45}{20}\right)^{0.23}\times \left(\dfrac{40}{20}\right)^{0.56}$$

Comment: This seems to be correct for this example. But I'm not able to generalize... What would the formula be?

Comment: His general formula is $20(2.25)^{p_1}2^{p_2}$.